# Setting categories from another column values

Tags: r

I want to create a nez column category with 3 values possible,low,medium and high .Those valueswill depend on another column.I tried this following butit s only working for medium and high. Low is not taken.

```
admission$category[admission$gre == 0 | admission$gre <= 440]= "low"


admission$category[admission$gre == 440 | admission$gre <= 580] = "Medium"

admission$category[admission$gre == 580  | admission$gre >= 580] = "High"

admission$category=as.factor(admission$category)
```

> errors :
>   admission$category[admission$gre == 0 | admission$gre <=
>   440]= "low"
>   Warning message:
>   In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, admission$gre ==
>   0 | admission$gre <= 440,  :   invalid factor level, NA generated
>
> str du df   category   : Factor w/ 2 levels "High","Medium": 2 1 1 1 2
>   1 2 2 2 1 ...

Answer (score 0):

You have the error because category is a factor.

```
set.seed(100)
admission = data.frame(category=sample(letters[1:4],100,replace=TRUE),
gre = sample(1:600,100))
admission$category = as.character(admission$category)
admission$category[admission$gre <= 440]= "low"
admission$category[admission$gre > 440 & admission$gre <= 580] = "Medium"
admission$category[admission$gre > 580] = "High"
table(admission$category)

  High    low Medium 
     3     69     28
```

or you can simply do:

```
admission$category = cut(admission$gre,breaks=c(0,440,580,+Inf),
labels=c("low","Medium","High"))
table(admission$category)
low Medium   High 
69     28      3
```